# Is it possible to get Yii2 cookie validation key if value is known

Tags: php, cookies, yii2

In my Yii2 application I am using cookies to store a user referral code. The user knows what their referral code is and I was wondering if it is possible to derive the cookie validation key that is used to hash the string. Also, what would be the potential concerns if the cookie validation key was known?

Here is the link to the Yii2 guide portion on cookies if it helps give more context: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Yii2 uses SHA-256 to hash those strings. It's pretty mush [irreversible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/28963/sha-256-reversing-a-string-of-equal-length). So this is not a security leak.

If somebody had your cookie validation key, they could forge a cookie. That is the real threat, so keep your cookie validation key safe.